# How to close EntityManagerFactory when jar is undeployed?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly, entitymanager

I have a jar that has the following factory for creating EntityManagerFactory.

```
public class PL4BaseDAO {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PL4BaseDAO.class);

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pl4sms-persistence");

    public static EntityManager getEm() {
        logger.info(emf.toString());
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

persistence.xml

This is the persistence unit that I created : -

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="pl4sms-persistence">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.ecomm.pl4sms.persistence.entities.SQL_RECIEPT_SMS</class>
        <class>com.ecomm.pl4sms.persistence.entities.Properties</class>
        <properties>
            <!-- Hibernate Properties -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"
                value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
                value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pl4sms" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"
                value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username"
                value="username" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password"
                value="password" />
            <property name="hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister"
                value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings"
                value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
                value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit"
                value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans"
                value="true" />         
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My JNDI lookup : -

```
public static final String EJB_PROP_DAO = "java:global/pl4sms-dbaccess-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies/PropertiesDao!com.ecomm.pl4sms.interfaces.PropertiesInterface";

public static final String EJB_SQL_RECIEPT_DAO = "java:global/pl4sms-dbaccess-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies/Sql_Reciept_SMSDao!com.ecomm.pl4sms.interfaces.Sql_Reciepts_SMSInterface";

public static Sql_Reciepts_SMSInterface getSQLREcieptDao() {

        Sql_Reciepts_SMSInterface sql_Reciepts_SMSInterface = null;
        try {
            sql_Reciepts_SMSInterface = (Sql_Reciepts_SMSInterface) getContext().lookup(EJB_SQL_RECIEPT_DAO);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return sql_Reciepts_SMSInterface;
    }

public static PropertiesInterface getPropertyDAO() {

        PropertiesInterface propertyDaoInterface = null;
        try {
            propertyDaoInterface = (PropertiesInterface) getContext().lookup(EJB_PROP_DAO);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return propertyDaoInterface;

    }
```

The jar is used as a driver to be used by 3 other wars.
I want to close the EntityManagerFactory when the jar is undeployed in jboss, How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is there a reason to not use the one that can be injected?

Comment: The project is based on EJB and I am using JNDI lookup to get the DAO layer

Comment: EJB's can inject an EntityManagerFactory with a `@PersisttenceUnit` annotation if you've got JPA configured.

Comment: [@James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152794/james-r-perkins) So If I inject the EMF using @PersisttenceUnit the EMF will close when the jar is undeployed, correct?

Comment: Correct. The application server manages the lifecycle.

Comment: [@JamesR.Perkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152794/james-r-perkins) I tried the approach, but when I try to initialize the application, I am getting SQL Error: 42102, SQLState: 42S02 Table not found.

Comment: I'm not sure what would cause that. It must be some kind of configuration issue.

Comment: [@JamesR.Perkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152794/james-r-perkins) I have added the configurations that I have used in the module.